# Simple Iteration Array Error Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, iteration

This code is trying to take two simple arrays and apply them to a function and spit the results out into a new array.  I have tried several different fixes from Stack and nothing seems to be helping.  The code is giving an "index 15 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4" error.  It is also worth noting that this is my first Python code so I am struggling a bit.  I am much more used to Java.  I'm assuming its a simple error, however I have yet to find the solution on Stack.

```
import math
import numpy as np

aVec = np.array ([3.14, 15, 9, 26]);
bVec = np.array ([[2.71], [8], [28], [182]]);

lengthaVec = len(aVec);
yVec = [lengthaVec]
i = 0;
for i in aVec:
   yVec.append (math.sqrt(math.pow(np.transpose((aVec[i])), 2) +             math.pow(bVec[i], 2)));

print yVec
```

Comment: Python does not require semi-colons to terminate statements. Semi colons can be used to delimit statements if you wish to put multiple statements on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your iterator, `for i in aVec` -> This won't be able to access all values in array.

Check following code:

```
import math
import numpy as np

aVec = np.array ([3.14, 15, 9, 26])
bVec = np.array ([[2.71], [8], [28], [182]])

lengthaVec = len(aVec)
yVec = [lengthaVec]
i = 0
for i in range(len(aVec)):
   yVec.append (math.sqrt(math.pow(np.transpose((aVec[i])), 2) + math.pow(bVec[i], 2)))
```

Comment: That seems to be the case.  However I also have several other for loops working without that bit in the loop.  But as far as this example goes it works.

Comment: if you will execute len(aVec), it will return value 4. It is just one way of iterating through loop. You can also use other methods for that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what I get when I iterate on `aVec` - the values from that array, not indices.

```
In [607]: for i in aVec:
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     
3.14
15.0
9.0
26.0
```

The 15 in the error comes from this iteration, and trying to use the value as index, `aVec[15]`

```
"index 15 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4"
```

Change the iterator to `range...`, so successive values are 0,1,2,3

```
for i in range(aVec.shape[0]):
    print(math.sqrt(math.pow(np.transpose((aVec[i])), 2) +math.pow(bVec[i], 2)));

4.147734321289154
17.0
29.410882339705484
183.84776310850236
```

There are other ways of iterating, and probably also of doing the calc without iteration (see following edits)

`zip` is nice for coordinated iteration:

```
for a,b in zip(aVec, bVec):
     print(math.sqrt(math.pow(np.transpose((a)), 2) +math.pow(b, 2)));
     .
```

but if `a` is 1 value, transpose is meaningless. So we can drop that.

And we can drop the iteration (or move it to compiled code) with:

```
In [619]: np.sqrt(aVec**2+bVec.T**2)
Out[619]: array([[   4.14773432,   17.        ,   29.41088234,  183.84776311]])
```

I had to use `bVec.T` (transpose) because you define it as a (4,1) array, while `aVec` has shape (4,).  Simply doing

```
aVec**2 + bVec**2
```

produces a (4,4) set of values - the 'outer' sum.  Nice in some cases, but probably not what you want here.

Another way - join both into a 2d array, square all elements, sum and sqrt:

```
np.sqrt((np.array((aVec, bVec.ravel()))**2).sum(0))
np.linalg.norm(np.array((aVec, bVec.ravel())),axis=0)
```

`ravel()` is another way of making `bVec` 1d like `aVec`.

Answer (score 0):

In python iterators often make use of the `range` feature. You were correct in surmising that your code can be corrected simply. Looking at your `for` loop:

```
i = 0
for i in aVec:
```

becomes, simply:

```
for index in range(1,len(aVec):
    yVec.append (math.sqrt(math.pow(np.transpose((aVec[index])), 2)+ math.pow(bVec[index], 2)));
```

Here we have properly assigned the loop to the length of the array.